# Making a longtable that does not interfere with table numbering

Tags: tables, floats, longtable

I would like to use `longtable` to make list of abbreviations in the front matter of my thesis.  I did not caption it, so it (rightly) does not show up in my list of tables.  However, it **does** throw off the numbering of the rest of the tables -- in other words, what should be Table 1 is now captioned and listed in the list of tables as Table 2.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\listoftables

The table I don't want to be numbered:
\begin{longtable}{ll}
\textbf{acac} & acetylacetonate \\
\textbf{Ar} & aryl \\
\end{longtable}

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\caption{The table that I want to be Table 1}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
column 1 & column 2 \\ \hline
77 & 43 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

What is the best way to prevent this mis-numbering to happen?  I considered creating a new float environment for this one case, but that seems inelegant.

Comment: yes sorry about that, just put `\addtocounter{table}{-1}` after the longtable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After long table add `\addtocounter{table}{-1}` which will decrement temporery value of counter table:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\listoftables

The table I don't want to be numbered:
\begin{longtable}{ll}
\textbf{acac} & acetylacetonate \\
\textbf{Ar} & aryl \\
\end{longtable}
    \addtocounter{table}{-1}%<-- decrement table counter

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\caption{The table that I want to be Table 1}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
column 1 & column 2 \\ \hline
77 & 43 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Damn, you were quicker with the `\addtocounter` -- way ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`\addtocounter{table}{-1}` is easy, `\SuspendCounters{table}` from `assoccnt` package (with `globalsuspend` option) works too. Use `\ResumeSuspendedCounters` at the appropiate place then.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[globalsuspend=true]{assoccnt}


\SuspendCounters{table}
\begin{document}
\listoftables

The table I don't want to be numbered:
\begin{longtable}{ll}
\textbf{acac} & acetylacetonate \\
\textbf{Ar} & aryl \\
\end{longtable}
\ResumeSuspendedCounters

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\caption{The table that I want to be Table 1}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
column 1 & column 2 \\ \hline
77 & 43 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table} 


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the package author will approve, but this should work:

1. in the code of `\longtable`, set a new conditional to false
2. in the code of `\LT@caption`, set this conditional to true
3. in the code of `\endlongtable`, check the value of the conditional: if it's `true`, a caption has been typeset in the `longtable`, do nothing; if it's `false`, no caption has been used, step down the `table` counter.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\LT@caption}
  {\bgroup}
  {\bgroup\global\LTpatch@captiontrue}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\longtable}
  {\par}
  {\par\global\LTpatch@captionfalse}
  {}{}
\apptocmd{\endlongtable}
  {\ifLTpatch@caption\else\addtocounter{table}{-1}\fi}
  {}{}
\newif\ifLTpatch@caption
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\bigskip

The table I don't want to be numbered:
\begin{longtable}{ll}
\textbf{acac} & acetylacetonate \\
\textbf{Ar} & aryl \\
\end{longtable}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{The table that I want to be Table 1}
\medskip
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
column 1 & column 2 \\ \hline
77 & 43 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The package author will definitely scold you for this vile patching ;-)

Comment: The package author never reads your answers, so won't notice.